# Android speed-up application when we use multi library on Gradle

Tags: android

I'm using multi library which they are installed by `Gradle` on my appliaction, after opening application each time i get simple delay on opening application such as 10 second :| if i download libraries instead of using and installing by `Gradle`, that cause of speed up my application or not?

My `Gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding-appcompat-v7:0.4.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding-design:0.4.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.2.1'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.2.1'
    compile 'frankiesardo:icepick:3.2.0'
    provided 'frankiesardo:icepick-processor:3.2.0'
    compile('io.socket:socket.io-client:0.7.0') {
        exclude group: "org.json", module: "json"
    }
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.github.devlight.navigationtabbar:library:+'
    compile 'com.joanzapata.iconify:android-iconify-fontawesome:2.2.2'
    compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.chyrta:AndroidOnboarder:+'
    compile 'com.github.lamydev:android-notification:3.0'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'
    compile 'com.bugsnag:bugsnag-android:+'
    compile 'com.github.liuguangqiang.swipeback:library:1.0.2@aar'
    compile 'com.wunderlist:sliding-layer:1.2.5'
    compile 'com.facebook.rebound:rebound:0.3.8'
    compile 'com.tumblr:backboard:0.1.0'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.jaredrummler:android-device-names:1.0.9'
    compile 'org.sufficientlysecure:html-textview:1.6'
    compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.5.2'
    compile 'com.kogitune:pre-lollipop-activity-transition:1.3.0'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
    compile 'com.alexvasilkov:foldable-layout:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularfillableloaders:1.2.0'
    compile 'cat.ereza:customactivityoncrash:1.5.0'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher:2.1.3'
    apt 'com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher-processor:2.1.3'
    compile 'com.github.goka.flickableview:flickableview:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.Kennyc1012:BottomSheet:2.1.2'
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:1.0.3'
    compile('com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:2.0.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile project(':lib-searchview')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No because gradle saves them locally, you can go to your gradle.properties and set these values and enable the gradle to use more of your machine compute power.

```
-Xms4096m
-Xmx4096m
-XX:MaxPermSize=2048m
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled 
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-Dfile.encoding=utf-8
```

Comment: can i show simple activity to load and show application? such as progressbar, before all activities?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question?

Comment: it seems my application speed is normally when i set your settings on gradle, please let me to test more that

Comment: You can increase the values of the paramters

Comment: it is not dangerous?

Comment: No, your machine OS will prevent the gradle from taking too much resources